# Is there a shortcut to switch on result of fn(case_value)?

Tags: php, switch-statement

```
switch (true) {
    case array_key_exists('view', $load):
        # code...
        break;
    case array_key_exists('model', $load):
        # code...
        break;
    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
```

this code works fine. but this is laborious. what is it shortcut? like this

```
switch ($a = array_key_exists($a, $load)) {
    case 'view':
        # code...
        break;
    case 'model':
        # code...
        break;
    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
```

But this not works

Comment: your second switch can only be `true` or `false` not `view`, `model`...

Comment: No, it is not possible to express it any other way using `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no shortcut for such an operation in PHP.

However, the original code should *probably* be written as

```
if (array_key_exists('view', $load)) {
    // ..
} else if (array_key_exists('model', $load)) {
    // ..
} else {
    // ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#check if exists
if(array_key_exists($a, $load))  

#check what exists
switch ($a) {
    case 'view':
        # code...
        break;
    case 'model':
        # code...
        break;
    default:
        # code...
        break;
}

#case for nothing matched
else{
  # code...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't have the same results as the OPs code (which is an abuse of switch vs. if/else-if.)

Comment: @user2864740, *This doesn't have the same results as the OPs code*, please elaborate more, e.g. what's the difference? as I can't see any.